# How to scale properly in swift and simulate depth

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground, depth

I want to zoom in or zoom out, the foreground and background should scale properly. Instead of scaling two separate elements, I **scale to 1.2 the main layer** and set the **background element to 0.8 scale**

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYeXO.png)

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

//Basic dimensions that we will use more later
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)

//Create a scene, add something to it
var scene = SKScene(size: frame.size)
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)


let layer = SKNode()

let background = SKNode()
let foreground = SKNode()

let foregroundBox = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(400), height: 40))
foregroundBox.position.y = -50
foregroundBox.zPosition = 101

let backgroundBox = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.gray, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(400), height: 40))
backgroundBox.position.y = 0
backgroundBox.zPosition = 9

foreground.addChild(foregroundBox)
background.addChild(backgroundBox)

background.setScale(0.8)

scene.addChild(foreground)
layer.addChild(background)

scene.addChild(layer)

// Should make the gray box the same size as the brown
layer.setScale(1.2)

//Set up the view and show the scene
let view = SKView(frame: frame)
view.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Both of the boxes have 400 width, but the background element have setScale(0.8).

By scaling the **parent layer to 1.2 (20%)** it should make the **background element to have 400 width** again?

PS. I don't add **foreground** to the main layer, in order to see the problem

```
scene.addChild(foreground)
```

Comment: 0.8*1.2=0.96, not 1, so your math is wrong. You need to set scale to 1/0.8=1.25 to get back the original size.

Comment: Thanks @DávidPásztor thats correct! I don't why I thought the scaling is 20%